# php mysql - query and sorting with multiple entries

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have following database (MYSQL//InnoDB) from a standard php project

```
Database: Event

Table 1: (Persons)
uid pid name     cat_pid
1   22  John     34
2   22  Samuel   34
3   55  Alex     60
4   22  Karl     34
.   ..  .....    ..

Table 2: (Category)
uid pid name
1   34  VIP 
2   45  Standard
3   60  Guest
4   62  another group
.   ..  .....
```

How can i query/foreach this result? Display no empty results and sort by Category name (ASC).

```
- VIP   
-- John
-- Samuel
-- Karl
- Guest 
-- Alex
```

In detail: output format with html/php:

```
<header>VIP<\header>    
<ul>
  <li>John<\li> 
  <li>Samuel<\li>
  <li>Karl<\li>
<\ul>  
<header>Guest<\header>  
<ul>
  <li>Alex<\li>
<\ul>  

SELECT t1.uid, t1.pid, t1.name, t1.cat_id, t2.uid, t2.pid, t2.name
FROM persons t1, category t2
WHERE t1.cat_id = t2.pid
ORDER BY t2.pid
```

the main focus is on the PHP output as described above ( a detailed mysql walkthrough is NOT important/needed ) any good suggestions?

Comment: Is it PHP related (OR) MySQL?

Comment: the question is (and it dont needs a big walkthrough)...how to render this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to explicit joins.

So the focus is on php. I would say order by category, such as name.

Have a $currentCat for knowing what category you are currently processing,

have a boolean var outside of loop set such as `bFirstUse=true`.

Start looping through result set such that

if `$bFirstUse=true`, set it to `false` AND set $currentCat=the category you are now processing.

When current category in row you are using is different than $currentCat, set $currentCat to it, plop in your `<header>$currentCat<\header><ul>`    and then wrap the name.

(1) note that when $currentCat changes, you first echo a `</ul>` but not the first time it changes (`$bFirstUse=true`, but set it to false) .... so as to close out the previous category.

when the loop is finished, echo `</ul>`

that sorta concept.

Comment: setting a flag is a good suggestion to remember the catname...i will try this thanks.

Comment: you changed Regular to Standard, I am saddened :>

Comment: i used two queries (first loop through categories second loop through the guys) with the flag suggestion it works fine.